# User agent stylesheet override - Paragraph text

Tags: html, css, text, user-agent

I have some paragraph text, as below, however in chrome it keeps adding a 1em margin to the left hand side. Here is my code:

```
.bold { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#333337; font-weight:bold; margin:0px; -webkit-margin: 0px!important;}
```

Here is the HTML defining the text.

```
<p class="bold">Account Name</p>
```

As always, thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
This is the user agent stylesheet that is doing the overriding

```
p {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide something that illustrates the problem? Setting `margin` to `0` works perfectly in Chrome (26 and Canary).

Comment: Well I have overridden those properties set by agent style sheet so its obviously something else - back to the drawing board

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, maybe with some more context? I'd guess it's something else creating that gap, but it's hard with just the above to go on. Can you maybe inspect the paragraph in the Chrome dev tools and screenshot the 'Computed style' section?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

In your specific case, this should help:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a simple reset I've put in place (aswell as adding that to it) and its still not working. The reset I put in place was `* {margin:0; padding:0;}`